# Plot issue with an injected argument in the function

Tags: plotting

I will explain the problem using a very simple toy model of the actual problem at hand which is rather complicated. I am plotting the following

```
With[{k = 0.1, a = 1}, Plot[1/(a + Sin[x*k]), {x, 0, \[Pi]}]]
```

which returns me a nice output. Now, I want to supplement the argument with a solution `sol[x,k]` from outside, so I use `Block` with regards to the scoping constructs, i.e.,

```
eq[α_, k_, x_] := Sin[k + α] == x*Cos[k]
sol[x_?NumericQ, k_ /; 0 <= k <= Pi]:= α/.NSolve[{eq[α, k, x], 0 <= α <= Pi}, α, Reals]
Block[{k = 0.1, a = 1}, Plot[1/(a + Sin[x*k + sol[x, k]]), {x, 0, \[Pi]}]]
```

However, since `sol[x,k]` has empty solutions at some parameter values, like e.g. `sol[1.1,0.1]`, so e.g., when I plug the solution `sol[1.1,k]` in the argument of `sin` inside `Block` it returns me an empty plot. While, I thought that it should return me the plot which is generated using the code `With`? i.e., the one without this extra factor in the argument, meaning, with `sol[x,k]=0`. Is it the correct way of plotting in such situations?. Since there are ranges in `x` where there is no solution, so does `Block` or `plot` know this when plotting for `x`?
**Edit:**
Let me consider another regime where there are two solutions, take for example `sol[0.2,k]` which has two solutions and `Block[..]plot[..]` with `sol[0.2,k]` gives back the following output
[image]

But, plugging `sol[x,k]` inside the argument and `Block[..]plot[..]` gives
[image]

Comment: `sol[…]` returns a list of solutions, which is what causes the issues (since `Plot` expects the expression in the first argument to return a single number)

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks, yes this is what I suspected because there are various solutions in different regimes of parameter `x`, so how to fix this to get the correct output? I edited the question with more information now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a trivial problem, as usually `Plot` can handle multiple solutions as demonstrated above. The problem happens because the number of solutions changes.

There are two simple wokrarounds.

You could just plot `First` and `Last` solutions by solving twice:

```
eq[\[Alpha]_, k_, x_] := Sin[k + \[Alpha]] == x*Cos[k]
sol[x_?NumericQ, k_ /; 0 <= k <= Pi] := \[Alpha] /. 
  NSolve[{eq[\[Alpha], k, x], 0 <= \[Alpha] <= Pi}, \[Alpha], Reals]
Block[{k = 0.1, a = 1},
 Plot[{
   1/(a + First@Sin[x*k + sol[x, k]]),
   1/(a + Last@Sin[x*k + sol[x, k]])
   }, {x, 0, \[Pi]},
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Or you solve once and then sort out your solutions later

First we solve for meany values of x

```
solutions = 
  Block[{k = 0.1, a = 1}, 
   Table[{x, 1/(a + Sin[x*k + sol[x, k]])}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}]];
```

We assume, that there is always at least one solution and we make a list of points we can plot later

```
solutions1 = {#[[;; , 1]], #[[;; , 2, 1]]}\[Transpose] &@solutions;
```

Usinging `Select` we take all the points, where there was at least too solutions and make a list out of the second solution for plotting.

```
solutions2 = {#[[;; , 1]], #[[;; , 2, 2]]}\[Transpose] &@
   Select[solutions, Length[#[[2]]] > 1 &];

ListLinePlot[{solutions1, solutions2}]
```

[image]

Comment: In the first part of your answer something bad happened when you copied the code. It has all sorts of `\\` marks that don't belong there. Try to copy and paste again.

Comment: @Johu, Thanks. There are however some extra '\` marks in your code above. The second code you posted looks very tricky :-)

Comment: Sorry of the failed paste. It is now fixed and I added explanations for the second solutions. I think there is no way to get the same task done concisely and using much easier code. I actually learned quite a bit by reading the code of other people at SE. I hope you can also get something from it.

Comment: @Johu thanks. One last clarification. If there is say 3 solutions, then with regards to your first code, can we implement `First@[sol..]`, `Second@[sol..]` , `Last@[sol..]`?

Comment: No, then you need something similar to the second solutions, as Second is not defined if there is only 1 solution. Consider changing your `sol`, such that it would always give you the same number of solutions, even is some of them are the same. Then everything else is easy.

Comment: @Johu Thanks :-)